# bug with Safari transform:rotateY() transiton

Tags: css, debugging, safari, cross-browser, transform

I'm making a simple javascript game. At the moment, I'm facing a problem in the form of cross-browser compatibility with Safari. I have cards that flip on click through transform: rotateY() by 180deg, they also have a transition. And as far as I understand the problem is with him. Because if you remove it and leave the same flip logic, then this bug does not exist. If possible, please tell me how to solve it. You can go directly to the site itself -> https://oltensia.ru/

[bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmHvg.jpg)

Here is the whole code:

HTML:

```
<div class="game__square relative">
    <div class="game__square-side game__square-back">
        <div class="w-h-full relative">
            <div class="square-back square-side stage-1"></div>
            <div class="square-back square-side stage-2"></div>
            <div class="square-back square-side stage-3"></div>
            <div class="square-back square-side stage-4"></div>
            <div class="square-back square-side stage-5"></div>
            <div class="square-back square-side stage-6"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="w-h-full absolute flex-centered left-top-0">
            <span class="question-mark">?</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="game__square-side game__square-front">
        <div class="w-h-full relative">
            <div class="square-front square-side stage-1"></div>
            <div class="square-front square-side stage-2"></div>
            <div class="square-front square-side stage-3"></div>
            <div class="square-front square-side stage-4"></div>
            <div class="square-front square-side stage-5"></div>
            <div class="square-front square-side stage-6"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="w-h-full absolute flex-centered left-top-0">
            <img class="game__square-img" src="./storage/img/main/game-field/square-front/chest.png">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Sass

```
.game__square
  border: none
  outline: none
  background: none
  cursor: pointer
  &-side
    @include w-h-full()
    @include left-top-0()
    position: absolute
    backface-visibility: hidden
    -webkit-transition: all 200ms linear
    -moz-transition: all 200ms linear
    -o-transition: all 200ms linear
    .square-side
      position: absolute
      @include left-top-0()
      @include w-h-full()

  &-back
    transform: rotateY(0deg)
    -ms-transform: rotateY(0deg)
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg)
    -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg)
    -o-transform: rotateY(0deg)
    .question-mark
      font-family: $ff-question-mark
  &-front
    transform: rotateY(180deg)
    -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg)
    -webkit-transform:  rotateY(180deg)
    -moz-transform:  rotateY(180deg)
    -o-transform:  rotateY(180deg)

  &.checked
    .game__square-back
      transform: rotateY(-180deg)
      -ms-transform: rotateY(-180deg)
      -webkit-transform:  rotateY(-180deg)
      -moz-transform:  rotateY(-180deg)
      -o-transform:  rotateY(-180deg)
    .game__square-front
      transform: rotateY(-180deg)
      -ms-transform:  rotateY(0deg)
      -webkit-transform:  rotateY(0deg)
      -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg)
      -o-transform:  rotateY(0deg)
```

Please, help me if it posible. I'll be very grateful

I tried to fix it by adding cross-browser ones, but I don't know which ones to add

Comment: Could you describe what the bug is? And make a small example, perhaps with just one flip card, and put it in your question. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example